# Gnu make: is it possible to delay include directive to secondary expansion?

Tags: include, makefile, gnu-make

I need to delay inclusion of dependency fragments until second expansion time because the make file I'm editing is itself an include file and I will not have a list of source files to generate the includes until secondary expansion.

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES = $(patsubst %.cc, depend/%.d, $(CC_SRC_FILES))

# the following does the work because the include argument is not a rule
# prerequisite therefore no secondary expansion occurs
include $$(AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES)

depend:
    -mkdir depend

all: autodepend

autodepend: depend autodepend_include

autodepend_include: $$(AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES)
    @echo \"$^\"

$$(AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES): depend

depend/%.d: | %.cc
    # generate .d files that do not exist
    $(COMPILE.cc) -E $*.cc > /dev/null

%.o: %.cc
    # update .d files that exist
    $(COMPILE.cc) -o $@ $<
```

Note the `COMPILE.cc` is a very long string that includes `-MP -MMD -MFdepend/$*.d` flags for auto dependency generation.

Comment: Why will you not have the list until second expansion time? Are you accounting for the make restart involved with built include files?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the name of _any_ include file until the end of the first phase.

Comment: What populates `CC_SRC_FILES`? What generates the `depend/%.d` files? What makes the list available during the second phase but not during the first?

Comment: `CC_SRC_FILES` is populated after the include directive in the make file that is the parent of the one I'm editing. I'll add code to show the rest.

Comment: Where does that populate `CC_SRC_FILES`?

Comment: It's in the parent make file (the one that includes the one I'm editing) _after_ the include directive. And I cannot rearrange the order to have `CC_SRC_FILES` come before the include.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a *good* solution for this but you might be able to make this work by adding another built include file and using the order make evaluates those in.

Comment: Ya I think I follow the general idea.

Comment: No offense meant but I'd be shocked if you did. =) The interaction I'm talking about is odd.

Comment: Turns out the horrible hack might not be necessary and a much more mundane "hack" is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know that there's a clean solution to this problem but with a bit of a hack you can get you what you want.

Given a main `Makefile` of:

```
$(info main one)

include depend.mk

$(info main two)

CC_SRC_FILES := $(addsuffix .c,a b c d e f)

$(info main three)
```

and a `depend.mk` of:

```
$(info depend one)

AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES = $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(CC_SRC_FILES))
$(info AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES := $(AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES))
$(info MAKE_RESTARTS := $(MAKE_RESTARTS))
$(info CC_SRC_FILES := $(CC_SRC_FILES))

$(info depend two)
```

you get the following output when you run `make`:

```
main one
depend one
AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES :=
MAKE_RESTARTS :=
CC_SRC_FILES :=
depend two
main two
main three
make: `all' is up to date.
```

Which isn't surprising given the order of assignment and inclusion of files, etc.

Here's where the horrible hack comes in.

When make encounters an `include` directive that references a file that doesn't exist make sticks the file in a list of "missing `include` files" and continues parsing the makefile.

When it gets to the end of the makefile(s) it then tries to treat each entry in that list as a potential goal target<sup>[1](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles)</sup> and attempts to make the file.

Once the makefiles have been built make restarts itself and tries again.

You can use this to capture the value of `CC_SRC_FILES` in an built makefile that your makefile includes and have it be visible when you need it.

If we make `depend.mk` look like this:

```
$(info depend one)

include hack.mk

AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES = $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(CC_SRC_FILES))
$(info AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES := $(AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES))
$(info MAKE_RESTARTS := $(MAKE_RESTARTS))
$(info CC_SRC_FILES := $(CC_SRC_FILES))

$(info depend two)

hack.mk: $(if $(MAKE_RESTARTS),,force)
        @echo creating hack.mk
        @echo 'CC_SRC_FILES := $(CC_SRC_FILES)' > '$@'

force: ;
```

Then our output from `make` becomes:

```
main one
depend one
depend.mk:3: hack.mk: No such file or directory
AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES :=
MAKE_RESTARTS :=
CC_SRC_FILES :=
depend two
main two
main three
creating hack.mk
main one
depend one
AUTO_DEPENDENCY_FILES := a.d b.d c.d d.d e.d f.d
MAKE_RESTARTS := 1
CC_SRC_FILES := a.c b.c c.c d.c e.c f.c
depend two
main two
main three
make: `all' is up to date.
```

Which gives us the value where we want it.

This isn't pretty but it does work.